# Change Media Uploader default directory

Tags: plugin-development, media, media-library, uploads

I am using WordPress Media Library in my plugin in the backend. How to change the upload path for it dynamically? Can it be done during the enqueue, or when creating it in JavaScript?

I am using `wp_enqueue_media()` in `admin_enqueue_scripts` action, and later creating the media frame in Javascript using `wp.media`.

I've managed to change the directory when uploading using `plupload_default_params` filter, but I don't know how to hook into the `query-attachments` action that queries the files into the library.

**Update:** After hours of tinkering I gave up and I went with a different solution. I am adding a new setting on plugin's edit page and resetting it otherwise. This way I can access the option in ajax calls.

```
function change_upload_dir( $args ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $form = false;
        if( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) {
            $form = get_option( 'test_edit_' . $user_id );
        }
        if($form || isset($_GET['type']) || isset($_POST['subfolder'])) {
            // change upload path
```

And in the plugin construct:

```
    if( !(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) 
       && false === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-content') ) {
        $edit = get_option( 'test_edit_' . get_current_user_id() );
        if ( $edit && $edit != '' ) {
            update_option( 'test_edit_' . get_current_user_id(), '' );
        }
    }
```

This works fine, unless the user opens a new tab and the setting gets reset.
It's fine for now, but I'd really like to know if there is an easier way to do that.

Comment: By "it can be a good alternative to use in a plugin."  I meant an alternative to `wp_enqueue_media()` that can be used in a plugin.

Comment: Why not to move the file after it was uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

Might wanna look at

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/

In definition there is a hook `upload_dir`, you can use that to change `path`.

Haven't tried or tested it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: I am using `upload_dir` hook to run my `change_upload_dir` function, but unfortunately it doesn't work for Media Library's AJAX queries and uploads and I don't want to set it globally, as I want standard upload directory for posts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the default media upload location, you need to edit the wp-config.php file located in the root directory of your WordPress installation. If you want upload directory to be wp-content/files then you will need to place the following code in `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

If you want the upload directory to be outside wp-content, like `http://www.example.com/files/` then you need to set upload path in `wp-config.php` like this:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'files' );
```

Remember you can still choose whether or not you want uploaded files to be organized in month/year folders in **Settings » Media**.

[Function Reference /wp_upload_dir – WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/)